# SAS Assignment Statement without even sign

Tags: sas

I'm studying for a SAS certification exam, and I came across an unexplained behavior. Note the data step below:

`data D;`
`A+1;`
`A+1;`
`A+1;`
`run;`

Question 1: Why this step does not result in error?
Question 2: Why a variable A is created, and its value is 3 and not missing?
Question 3: Why when I change + for - , it results in error?

I have searched about it and i couldn't find nothing, even in SAS documentation

Comment: if you would like to study answers that come with explanations, you can check out https://sasensei.com (quiz site for SAS).  Disclaimer - I'm the founder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A+1 is sum statement initially A or anything in that form is automatically set to 0 and in your second line of code it becomes 0 +1 = 1 then this value is in A is retained that is A becomes 1 and then when you add 1 in your 3 line of code becomes 2 and then 3. There is nothing of sort is there for -, so it errors when you do A-1, becomes A is not defined, where as in A +1  A is automatically set to 0. Below is the documentation for Sum statement

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000289454.htm.

Please see in below comment of @longfish explains to do the samething for  -1, you need to do A+-1

Comment: Note that to subtract a value, A+ -1 will work

Comment: modified my answer as per your suggestion @longfish. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That is a SUM statement. The syntax is

```
variable + expression ;
```

That is why replacing the `+` with `-` did not work.  It no longer followed the pattern above.  If you want to subtract then negate the expression.

```
variable + - (expression) ;
```